# Go to an old commit and push temporary changes to remote

Tags: git, bitbucket, smartgit

I have a repo on Bitbucket, and we have a specific branch called "staging" that when we push to it, it updates the code on our server automatically.

I need to go back like 10 commits earlier to see if a bug was introduced in those last commits.

Locally,  tried to git `checkout <commit-sha>` while being in my staging branch, and I had to create a new branch (I'm using SmartGit). How do I then use that new branch for staging, or just revert from staging itself and push to Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Force-push to the staging branch

You can temporarily hard reset the staging branch on the remote by force-pushing to it from your new branch, which could be an option as long as you have an agreement with your coworkers that this is just temporary, and that they should not base new code off of the reset staging branch.

Assuming that the new branch you've created is called X, you can do the following:

```
git push bitbucket X:staging -f
```

`X:staging` is a "refspec", that says "take the local branch X, and push it's contents to the staging branch on the remote". `-f` is of course the force push option.

### Option 2: Temporarily revert the last 10 commits on the staging branch

Another option is to temporarily revert those last 10 commits, push to your staging branch, then hard reset back to the original state when you're done testing, and force push the original state back.

You can revert the commits using `git revert`.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket has a feature for this built in, although it does so graphically. Go to the repo and swap to the branch in question. Then find the button on the left labled "Commits". From here, you can click on any of the commit hashes and it will show you all of the changes at that point in time. If you need to actually revert back to that point, you can use `git revert HEAD~<number of commits to revert>`.

Comment: Are you actually able to reset or revert the state of the remote branch on Bitbucket through their web interface though, or would you still need to do that from the command line?

Comment: I have no idea if you can through their web interface. I much prefer command line when it comes to that, so I haven't even attempted. It can definitely be done through command line though.